# CoreData main application and background process, with the same data

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data

I'am planning to have a **main OSX application**, which the user can launch and a **background process, which starts on OSX startup** and runs prior to the main application

I need a CoreData database, to keep track of some changes... this database should be the same for the background task and foreground app...

What are the options?

1. Is it possible, that both access the same sqlite (which will be
   located in app bundle?)? By setup with the same .sqlite file?
2. Should they have two identical databases, which they synchronize?
       can this synchronisation be automated?
3. Should there be one database for the background process and the
       main application should communicate with the background process?

Comment: What's the purpose of the background process? Why not do that work in a GCD queue? What is the source of the changes? It would probably help you if you use standard Core Data terminology: NSPersistentStore, not sqlite, for instance. I'm not sure precisely what you mean when you say "database". Is that the persistent store, or the entire Core Data stack?

Comment: the background task should manage given files, based on the server communication... the application should provide a management interface for these files with further possibilities... the user needs to log in

Comment: can two different processes open the same sqlite file and set it up as a NSPersistentStore?

Answer (score 0):

Using a background process to update the datastore is fighting the frameworks. Also, your background process (and your main process, for that matter) won't be able to update the .sqlite file that lives in your bundle.

Instead of using a background process, use a background queue (via Grand Central Dispatch, and `NSManagedObjectContext -performBlock:`. Keeping the logic within one application will make your life easier. Your communication happens within the application, instead of having to use XPC.

Don't forget to handle the case of a partial, interrupted, update. The sequence I suggest is:

1. Application launches.
2. Background queue launches, pulls updated info from server, creates updated datastore using a temporary name.
3. If background update succeeds, main queue of application closes the old version of the datastore, then replaces it with the updated datastore. There is API to do this atomically.
4. Main thread reopens datastore and refreshes UI as needed.
5. If background update fails, reschedule an update attempt based on failure reasons (bad credentials, server unreachable, partial download, corrupt .sqlite).

If you're absolutely dead set on using two different processes, then you should still assume that the update might fail. So don't write to the live copy until you know you have a complete, valid, replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Apple achieve this in the Notes app using what they call a "cross process change coordinator". This allows the accountsd daemon and the Notes app to access the same CoreData sqlite database. Their class `ICNotesCrossProcessChangeCoordinator` in the NotesShared framework works by using `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` to post the notification of changes between the processes and merge them into each others' context. There are many more implementation details of the technique but this should point you in the right direction.